# How to get list of android apps running in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, background-process

I'm trying to build an app that shows which media player (Spotify, Google Play Music, etc.) that is currently being used. I've tried the "old" version with:

```
val manager = this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            val processes = manager.runningAppProcesses
            for (process in processes) {
                if (processName == process.processName) {
                    return true
                }
            }
```

This one only returns my app (which I read is normal)
and the "new version":

```
val usm = this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val appList =
                usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 10, time)
            for(process in appList){
                if (processName == process.packageName && process.lastTimeUsed > time - 1000*10 ) {
                    return true
                }
            }
```

This one returns me all the app and is close to what I want, but if an app is playing music in the background, it will not show.

Any idea on how to approach the problem?

Comment: This has not been practical for years, due to changes to Android to improve privacy and security.

Comment: So you're saying there's NO way of knowing who is playing music?

Comment: Correct. Beyond the technical issues, there are thousands of media player apps, not just two.

Comment: Well that's a bummer... I was only planning to intergrate the major ones (Spotify, Google play music, Apple Music)